# Apollo setContext can not save the token from the server

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo

I'd like to implement apollo-link-context/react-native/graphql, but Apollo setContext does not save an accessToken. If i check it with console.log i get undefined. And it looks like setContext calls before then i get tokens from the server. Therefore setContext can not get in time to save a token. Can somebody help me please

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo'
import { ApolloProvider as ApolloHooksProvider } from 'react-apollo-hooks'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain'
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator'

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000'
})

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const tokens = await Keychain.getGenericPassword()
  const accessToken = tokens.accessToken
  console.log('accessTokenSetContext', accessToken)
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: accessToken ? `Bearer ${accessToken}` : ''
    }
  }
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  connectToDevTools: true
})

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <ApolloHooksProvider client={client}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </ApolloHooksProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```